# Check if receiver is not disabled by other apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

There are a couple different apps in the Play Store that can disable receivers of other apps (AutoStart Manager, BootManager, etc.) and even some are shipped with the system itself (ASUS Auto-Start Manager). This causes misbehaviour in my app and I want to handle this situation.

Is there a way to check if any of my receivers have been disabled by one of these apps?

Comment: That would depend on how they are doing it. The two Play Store apps that you cite require root, so they can modify anything they want. You might experiment with [`PackageManager` and `getComponentEnabledSetting()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName)) to see if they are disabling the receiver itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Nope, solution from @CommonsWare does not function